# how to set up feed dialog

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I'm having trouble setting up a feed dialog.  I've created a developer account and a new app but I can't find any information about how to set it up to create a feed dialog.  There is plenty of info on the FB.ui script itself.

Presently the the FB.ui script returns the error:

API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

What do I need to do in the developer account to set up a Feed Dialog correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
Click on 'Edit app'
Select 'Website with Facebook Login'
Enter your website URL in the 'Site URL' field. Remember to add a trailing '/'

Here are two good tutorials to get you started:

[Working With Facebook Javascript SDK](http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/404-working-with-facebook-javascript-sdk)

[Publish Actions With Facebook Javascript SDK](http://www.loginworks.com/technical-blogs/406-publish-actions-with-facebook-javascript-sdk)

Comment: Thank you, that was confusing me as I don't actually want facebook login but couldn't see an alternative

Comment: pls accept this as answer by clicking the green tick if you're done with your problem